# Why would printing python dictionary work differently than writing it to file?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Working with sql connections in which I get a list on return containing 4 specific items for each selection row. I am running into an issue where the print output is different from an output text file.

When I print this list, it looks like it should, no problems.

```
>>>print(my_list)
>>>['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item1a', 'item2a', 'item3a', 'item4a']
```

I added in some labels to print these items with a label for their content description, doing the following:

```
labels = ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID4']
my_dictionary = {}
filename = '\\Somefilepath\\file.txt'
len_of_labels = len(labels)

with open(filename, "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for i, l in enumerate(my_list):
        my_dictionary[l] = labels[i % len_of_labels]
    for d in my_dictionary:
        f.write('{:15} : {:3}'.format(my_dictionary[d], d))
f.close()
```

If I use print instead of f.write, I get the anticipated output of:

```
ID1      item1
ID2      item2 
ID3      item3
ID4      item4
ID1      item1a
ID2      item2a 
ID3      item3a
ID4      item4a 
# And so one
```

but when writing to a text file using the above, It is cutting the length off shorter than the len item, and then stopping on the second iteration so it looks something like this:

```
ID1      item1
ID2      item2 
ID3      item3  
ID1      item1a
ID2      item2a 
# Does not give me all 4 on the first iteration and cuts off the second one
```

Comment: N.B. `f.close()` is redundant as the context manager (i.e. the with-block) will automagically close the file for you.

Comment: Other than adding `\n` to the `.write` statement (as ToddP has shown), I couldn't reproduce the "cutting off the second one". All rows and lines from the dictionary are printed. Perhaps try closing and reopening your text file?

Comment: OK, I went back and compared output to the actual list I have. If the Key : Value is the same as the previous iteration, it just doesnt print it.

Comment: First, you cannot have duplicate keys in a dictionary. All keys must be unique. Second, why do you need a dictionary at all? Why don't you just write the results from the list directtly to the file?

Comment: That was the solution I had to bring the list labels with x values over the contents of another list with y values and keep the order intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing and review with some help from others, the dictionary became the problem with same key:value pairs. Posting a working way of doing this with the formatting of alignments included.

```
with open(filename, "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for idx, value in enumerate(my_list):
    i = labels[idx % 3]
    f.write('{:15} : {:3}'.format(i, value))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're writing dictionary elements before the dictionary is completely created. Try separating creation and writing like this:

```py
# first create the dictionary
for i, l in enumerate(my_list):
    my_dictionary[l] = labels[i % len_of_labels]

# then write it to file
with open(filename, "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for d in my_dictionary:
        f.write('{:15} : {:3}\n'.format(my_dictionary[d], d))
```

Comment: Note the newline character `'\n'` in the `write` command.  ALso note that `f.close()` is unnecessary when using `with`.

Comment: Your code and OPs is equivalent. Creating the dict outside `with` is the same as creating in inside `with` but before writing .

Comment: That cleaned it up for sure, but still did not do the trick.  After comparing, I find that if the Key : Value is the exact same as the previous iteration, it just doesn't write it to the file. It is in the list, but the dictionary is clearing the like items

Comment: Oops, I agree with @rdas, sorry about that. It's cleaner to separate dictionary creation and file writing, but I agree the result is the same. Like above, I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Theerror was because my actual data is different than the test data I posted here, it contains duplicates when processed and because I combined the two lists into a dictionary, it did not add the key:value pairs that were duplicates.

Comment: I updated main post to include a working example that does not need a dictionary. Thanks all.